# Parse query only returning users sometimes?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm using parse.com in my android app to search my users table and display the results. It searches in multiple fields and returns all users that fit the search string. Here's my code:

```
String searchParams = searchText.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!searchParams.isEmpty()) {
                final ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
                listAdapter = new ListAdapter(activityContext, searchResults);
                listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

                ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryName = ParseUser.getQuery();
                queryName.whereContains("name", searchParams);
                ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryPhone = ParseUser.getQuery();
                queryPhone.whereContains("username", searchParams);
                ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryEmail = ParseUser.getQuery();
                queryEmail.whereContains("email", searchParams);
                ParseQuery<ParseUser> querySurname1 = ParseUser.getQuery();
                querySurname1.whereContains("surname1", searchParams);
                ParseQuery<ParseUser> querySurname2 = ParseUser.getQuery();
                querySurname2.whereContains("surname2", searchParams);

                List<ParseQuery<ParseUser>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseUser>>();
                queries.add(queryName);
                queries.add(queryPhone);
                queries.add(queryEmail);
                queries.add(querySurname1);
                queries.add(querySurname2);

                ParseQuery<ParseUser> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);

                mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.d("USERS", "Retrieved " + objects.size() + " Users");
                            if (objects.size() > 0) {
                                for (ParseObject dealsObject : objects) {
                                    Log.i("NAME", dealsObject.getString("name"));
                                    Log.i("PRIVATE", Integer.toString(dealsObject.getInt("private")));
                                    final SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();
                                    sr1.setName(dealsObject.getString("name"));
                                    sr1.setSurname1(dealsObject.getString("surname1"));
                                    sr1.setSurname2(dealsObject.getString("surname2"));
                                    sr1.setUid(dealsObject.getObjectId());
                                    Log.d("UID", dealsObject.getObjectId());


                                    if (dealsObject.getInt("private") == 0) {
                                        sr1.setEmail(dealsObject.getString("email"));
                                        sr1.setPhone(dealsObject.getString("username"));
                                    } else {
                                        sr1.setPhone("xxx-xxx-xxx");
                                        sr1.setEmail("xxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx");
                                    }

                                    ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) dealsObject.get("thumbnail");
                                    try {
                                        byte[] imageBytes = fileObject.getData();
                                        sr1.setImage(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length));
                                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                                        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
                                    }

                                    searchResults.add(sr1);
                                }
                                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                welcomeText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                pDialog.hide();
                            }
                            else if (objects.size() == 0)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.no_search_results, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                pDialog.hide();
                            }

                        } else {
                            Log.d("USERS", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

My problem is that even when searching for a user I know is there, most of the times it tells me that it found 0 users. If i keep running the search with the same search string, maybe one time out of 5 it will actually return a user. Another problem I've had is with users that have been deleted, yet the search still finds them and then the app throws a nullPointerException when it tries to pull info from them. Is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks for your time

Comment: first of all you need to put a condition whether the list is null or not, another thing is search might not be working if the usernames in the table may contain uppercase letters because parse doe not allows searching uppercase letters

Comment: I've edited the main post to include checking if the object list is empty after the query. I've heard about parse being case sensitive, so I'm searching for users exactly as I see them on the database, but still getting 0 results randomly, and only sometimes getting the result I'm expecting.

Comment: have you checked your logcat for any exceptions? may be there you could find something suspicious

Comment: No exceptions, just my Log.d telling me that it found 0 results. Sometimes, however, i notice that the Log.d gets called twice in a single query, and I've even seen it show me 0 and 2 results immediately afterwards.

Comment: you need to clear previous array list before you add new data to it

Comment: I don't think that's a problem, as the array list is created anew when the function is called (via OnClickListener on a button)